# How do I change the font color in ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

I can't seem to find a reasonable answer to this question.  I looked at Ubuntu Tweak and it's only for older versions of Ubuntu.  I have 12.4 LTS.

Comment: FWIW, new Ubuntu Tweak supports 13.04.  But what are you trying to change them to? Colorblind safe, inverted, not orange, etc.?

Comment: If you're comfortable editing .css files, check out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1913590&p=11632738#post11632738. I don't use Ubuntu anymore and so can't say if the workaround still works. Even if it does, you'll have to apply it each time the USC is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is based on Gnome and AFAIK, Gnome has got some tools to do such a thing (don't use those tools for a while, since 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope or something like that). They might be in Gnome customization menus. So install Gnome 3 (Gnome Shell and/or Gnome Classic) and have a look at their customization menus. Try also with MATE (Gnome 2 fork) packages.

PS : if somebody knows the real names of the packages of I am dealing with (Gnome custonization programs), feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I met the theme question like you when I use the gnome default theme Adwaita(Dark theme). The Ubuntu software center's font colour becomes unreadable.
Here is how I fix it.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
```

Then change these two line with whatever the color u want

```
@define-color light-aubergine #DED7DB;
@define-color super-light-aubergine #F4F1F3;
```

Hope it can fix your problem.